# Reading the contents of a file in a Sharepoint group folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, endpoint, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to read the contents of a file in a Sharepoint group folder using the Microsoft Graph Explorer, however the query I'm using doesn't seem to be working:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group_id>/drive/root/children/<filename>/$value
```

Is there a way to define a query that I can pull the file contents in Postman if Graph Explorer can't do it?

So after doing a bit of digging, if I substitute /$value with /content in Postman, I get the following:

```
Failure - Status Code 0,

{
    "isTrusted": true
}
```

Not sure what it means though.

Comment: Are you acquiring an auth token and providing it as a bearer token header in the Postman call?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I figured the issue out. I was making calls to the wrong path